# Polynomial set as a base

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Show that $\left\{ 1, x-1, x²-3x+1 \right\}$  is base of $ \mathbb{R}2[X]$  and find the coordinates of $2x²-5x+6$ in that base.

Proof for L.I:
$$
 \alpha (1) +  \beta (x-1) +  \gamma (x²-3x+1) = 0
$$
$$
 \alpha - \beta + \gamma = 0  \Rightarrow  \alpha = \beta - \gamma\\
 \beta x + 3\gamma x = 0 \Rightarrow \beta = -3\gamma\\
 \gamma x² = 0 \Rightarrow \gamma = 0\\
  \alpha,\beta,\gamma = 0
$$
Getting coordinates:
$$
 \alpha (1) +  \beta (x-1) +  \gamma (x²-3x+1) = 2x²-5x+6
$$
$$
\gamma = 2\\
\beta - 3\gamma = -5\\
\alpha - \beta +\gamma = 6\\
$$
$$
\beta = -5 +3*2 = 1\\
\alpha = 6-1 = 5\\
$$
$$
Coordinates = (5,1,2)
$$

Is my answer correct or incorrect? i'm kinda confused with polynomials in linear algebra... visualizing them as subspaces, bases...

Thanks!

Comment: Mostly correct. For the first part, you only showed linear independence; you may then say "these are three linearly independent vectors, and the space is three-dimensional, so they must be a base." For the first part, too, you can argue by bootstrapping: First $\gamma = 0$ by looking at the coefficient of $x^2$; then, since you already know $\gamma = 0$, you must have $\beta = 0$ looking at the coefficient of $x$, etc. Part 2 can be done similarly: get $\gamma$ first, then move that part to the RHS and calculate the RHS, then do the same for $\beta$, etc.

Comment: Thank you for commenting! Don't you think that's weird to think of polynomials as subspaces and basis? I get that a set can inherit vectorial space properties... but when in used to think in linear algebra, I thought that I was dealing with vectors in Rn...

Comment: It depends on why you are learning about vectors in the first place. If you will be a profesional mathematician or physicist, it will serve you well to develop a more general intuition, where you are able to "see vector spaces" where they do indeed exist, but they aren't as obvious. If on the other hand your only use for them is to draw proper technical graphs for engineering or architecture, say, then seeing vectors in polynomials up to a fixed degree will be pretty useless.

Comment: Nice explanation! Thanks again buddy. I'm in the second semester of physics... I'm building that kind of intuition that you've mentioned. Are you graduated in math, physics, or other exact sicence?

Comment: Got a phd in math over 20 years ago.

Comment: Amazing! Hope one day to get a phd... Working for it, but in physics. Any advice?